# show all the connected devices to a wifi

Tags: c#, android, vb.net, wifi

I am trying to write an application (visual Studio) to show all the connected device to my wifi. I was able to get the available SSID but is there any way
to list all the connected device to a specific SSID?  in C# or VB
any help that point me to the right direction would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the machine running the App is on the WiFi then all you have to do is **Ping** The IPs on the network.

```
If My.Computer.Network.Ping("198.168.XX.XX") Then
   'Add IP to list
   MsgBox("Server pinged successfully.")
Else
   MsgBox("Ping request timed out.")
End If
```

You need to be careful though to check the **Subnet Mask** of the machine that way you know what range of IP to ping.

Comment: Wow. I was thinking too hard.  Thanks Mederic

Comment: If this is what your looking for remember to validate as an answer. @JamesKM